# Why TeXnicCenter do not generate bibliography list?

Tags: bibliographies, texniccenter

*Sample code is taken from ShareLatex, where it works fine.*

**Why TeXnicCenter do not generate bibliography list?**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliography {Sample}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Sample.bib}

\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{biblatex} package}
\author{Share\LaTeX}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This document is an example of \texttt{biblatex} package using in bibliography management. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: With `biblatex` you have to run Biber, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). For a bit of background on what Biber does, see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864).

Comment: You should probably also remove the `\bibliography {Sample}` line, `\addbibresource{Sample.bib}` is enough (and `\addbibresource` is preferred over `\bbliography` in `biblatex`).

Comment: Thanks, I have spend two days, before to find the reason of problem.